# How to write Limit and Offset variable in URLEncoder

Tags: java, php, android

I've been tasked to retrieve a list of data from my MySQL server and display it in my Android Application. In the app, I'm supposed to pass some parameters over to the PHP file. These parameters will act as a search filter and is used in my Query. In the Query, there is a OFFSET and LIMIT that I have to set in order to limit the amount of data I want to see. Now my problem is that when I'm writing the code to pass the variables, I do not know how to write the URLEncoder line for them. Both the OFFSET and LIMIT is created via a method that I will create later on.

Here is my URLEncoder code.

```
case "historypage":{
                String uuid = params[1];
                String offset = params[2];
                String limit = params[3];
                try {
                    data = URLEncoder.encode("type", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("historypage", "UTF-8")
                            + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("uuid", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(uuid, "UTF-8");    
                    Log.e(TAG,"DATA: " + data);
```

This is my PHP code

```
$uuid = $_POST['UUID'];
        $limit = $_POST['limit'];
        $offset = $_POST['offset'];
        $result_array = [];
        $sql = "SELECT `temp_id`, `temp_data` FROM `onedb` WHERE `uuid` = '$uuid' LIMIT $offset,$limit";
        if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
```

Can someone advice me on how to write OFFSET and LIMIT in URLEncoder format? 
Or is there some other way to do this?

Comment: Please add logs of data variable also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
    String data_string= URLEncoder.encode("type","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("historypage","UTF-8")
   +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("uuid","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(uuid,"UTF-8")
   +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("offset","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(offset,"UTF-8")
   +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("limit","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(limit,"UTF-8");
```

Comment: Hi sir thank you for answering. This solved my problem.